# How to write a long os.path.join chain while complying to PEP8

Tags: python, pep8

I am using a long chain of **[os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)** to generate a path (it ensures the path will work on any OS).

```py
"metadata": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, os.path.join('ServiceProvider',os.path.join('config', os.path.join('metadata',os.path.join('gmail_metadata.xml'))))),
```

I would like to break it down into multiple lines the PEP8 way but I can't seem to make this happen.

I tried several things:

```py
"metadata": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 
            os.path.join('ServiceProvider',
            os.path.join('config', 
            os.path.join('metadata',
            os.path.join('gmail_metadata.xml'))))),
```

will get me the PEP8 error `continuation line under-indented for visual indentpep8(E128)`

and

```py
"metadata": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, os.path.join('ServiceProvider',
                                                    os.path.join('config', os.path.join('metadata',
                                                                                        os.path.join('gmail_metadata.xml'))))),
```

which is actually what PEP8 autofix did, I'm getting the `line too long` error.

If it is not possible to fix the PEP8 errors in this case I would still like to know how you would do it !

Comment: have a look at the pathlib module (standard library). It is a lot simpler to use to build complicated paths etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a list of all paths you want to join, and use list-unpacking (more details in the [PEP-3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) to unpack all your arguments and pass it to `os.path.join`

```
import os

#List of paths
li = [BASE_PATH,'ServiceProvider', 'config', 'metadata','gmail_metadata.xml']

#Join all paths by unpacking the list
path = os.path.join(*li)
print(path)
```

Answer (score 3):

The [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module will allow you to chain things in an interesting and flexible way. [Lovely tutorial here](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

```
import pathlib

# use / operator
path = pathlib.Path("BASE_DIR")
path /= "ServiceProvider" / "config" / "metadata" / "gmail_metadata.xml"
# or
path = pathlib.Path("BASE_DIR") / "ServiceProvider" / "config" / "metadata" / "gmail_metadata.xml"
# or
path = pathlib.Path("BASE_DIR") / 
       "ServiceProvider" / 
       "config" / 
       "metadata" / 
       "gmail_metadata.xml"
```

If you want to use `joinpath` from `os.path` module or `pathlib` then you doint have to nest the joins, one is enough.

```
path = os.path.join(*[BASE_DIR, "ServiceProvider", "config", "metadata", "gmail_metadata.xml"])
# or
path = pathlib.Path("BASE_DIR").joinpath(*["ServiceProvider", "config", "metadata", "gmail_metadata.xml"])
```

Comment: It is worth to mention that pathilb is available since python 3.4